# How to know since when a package has been installed on a linux system

Tags: linux, package-management, apt-get, packages, date-time

How can I find out the date (and time if possible) of installation of any package on Linux Operating system.

For Ubuntu and using apt-get

Comment: More information required. Which Linux distro and package system are we talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Try:
"dpkg -L [your package name] | xargs stat"

dpkg -L will list the files installed on your system from the package name that you enter(don't include the brackets).  The "xargs stat" side will take the input from the piped command and show you the status of the files found with the dpkg -L command.

This will give you a lot of information about the files which are related to the package.

If you know where the file is you can just use "stat /path/to/file/.

This is probably as close as you are going to get to finding when the package was installed as apparently posix standards do not include file birth dates.  [How to find creation date of file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91197/how-to-find-creation-date-of-file)

[This is an example](http://www.deanspicer.mooo.com/dpkg-L_example.txt) of the results that you will get.  I used the command "dpkg -L python-software-properties | xargs stat" to create these results.

Comment: thanks! does it also work for the packages installed using apt-get

Comment: Yes.  This link may help understand how the package managers work.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/309113/what-is-the-difference-between-dpkg-and-aptitude-apt-get